# How to get the return type from a .net core server call to the .net client method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-signalr

So i'm in the controller class of my .net core web api and i can successfully call methods in a .net winform client using signalR core. What i really need to do though is get a return value from that call so i can make my controller respond accordingly, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `signalr`, you invoke a remote call from server and you can pass any data/object, which is serialized (usually in json format by default). On the client side, you should have the same object and the same method. The framework will do the deserialization for you.

If you are using `rest` apis, the controller usually returns data/object (again usually in json by default). On the client side, you deserialize the return object from the rest call.

Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, i'm not using signalR i'm using signalR core (they do differ) so, in the server's controller class i'm having to use IClientProxy's SendAsync method which does not return a type, there are no other options either. So i was wondering if there is another way to call the client's method in order to get at it's return type.

Comment: @zappa, it should be the other way around, you client might call a server method to pass its type (although not sure why you'd do it that way), and then subscribe to a method used by the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is that you think should be the other way around.  I can call in both directions without any problems (provided i don't need a returned value), what i need to do though is what i've said above. If you think i'm trying to do something wrong you should say what it is and why, i could justify why i'm trying to do what i'm trying to do but i think that'll just add noise to the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up doing something similar to what this guy did http://richardssoftware.net/Home/Post/63

I'm using a database instead of his in memory collection, i'm not enamored by this solution though, it feels clunky.